# Illegal characters in path when using StreamReader

Tags: c#, file-io

I am having trouble with opening up a `StreamReader` object in C#.  I always receive the exception `Illegal characters in path`.  The only way I can get it to work is if I use the entire path name using the `@` symbol to not escape any `\` characters in the file path.  However, this doesn't really help me because I start with the two separate variables for the file's path and the file's name as output from another method (which can not be changed).

I've gone through eight permutations that all failed, which are commented out below for reference.  For the sake of readability here, pretend I'm declaring `dirIni` and `fileIni` instead of receiving their values as output from another method.  With that said, both declaration style 1 and 2 failed using all four concatenation methods.  What is going on here?  I've pretty much seen all four concatenation methods work in other examples.

**EDIT:**
I've simplified the code to show **1 version** of what breaks for me:

```
string dirIni = @"C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\MyApp 4.0\INI\";
string fileIni = @"PWTRANSACTION.INI";

try
{
    string transIniFullFileName = Path.Combine(dirIni, fileIni);

    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(transIniFullFileName))
    {
        // do StreamReader stuff...
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Here is the exception's stack trace:

```
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path)
   at TestApp.Form1.btnTestRead_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Dan\TestApp\Form1.cs:line 4977
```

Comment: Is it a problem with the space? perhaps?

Comment: There's a lot of noise in your code sample.  It would be easier to see what's going on if you simply had the failing code

Comment: You said (paraphrased) "pretend I'm not receiving the values from another method".  This could be hugely important...have you actually tried doing the way you've shown here? Are you 100% sure that the paths from the other methods don't have illegal characters?

Comment: @BugFinder - It's not an issue with the space, because the space works in the unescaped version.  Same goes for the period.

Comment: Here's how you should format your Short Self-Contained Example:   1.  Make a new project.  2.  Write the code that breaks.  3.  run the code to make sure that it still breaks.  4.  post THAT code and the error from THAT example.  Don't post code that works, with a comment regarding how it can break.  That only makes the problem harder to reproduce.

Comment: @SamIam - The reason the code is long is because I had eight different permutations fail.  If I simply had the failing code, it would be even longer.

Comment: @DanMaguire  Well then just post 1 failing version.  not the whole thing.  especially when the one that's not commented out is the working piece.

Comment: @DanMaguire The unescaped says "treat all the following as litterals" so its like backslashing EVERYTHING it needs to.. it shouldnt need to do space, but clearly there is a difference between the full escaped one and the not.

Comment: I copied the code and ran it with `string transIniFullFileName = "C:\\Users\\Dan\\AppData\\Local\\MyApp 4.0\\INI\\PWTRANSACTION.INI";`  uncommented and with the `@` version commented out. I only hit a `DirectoryNotFoundException`. Could there be magical characters in your local version that we're not seeing?

Comment: I also tried "declaration style 2" with concatenations #1 & #3 (#2 won't compile). Running those also did not produce the illegal character problem.

Comment: @SamIam - I thought I was being thorough by posting every version that failed, but I edited it to show just one version that fails.  Hopefully that's easier to read now.  Perhaps people will take back those down-votes.

Comment: The edited version of the code does not produce the illegal character error for me. I created the folders and file necessary, also. No exceptions, no illegal characters. Runs to the end.

Comment: @DanMaguire  one of the purposes of a Simple Self-Contained Correct Example(SSCCE) is for other people  to be able to copy and paste it into their instance of visual studio and see how it works for them.  That's why, as before, I've suggested doing it in a NEW PROJECT, and then, MAKING SURE THAT IT STILL FAILS THE SAME WAY.

Comment: @DanMaguire, can you verify that the strings you are providing us for both values (directory and file) are the same as what you're seeing in the debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was the method was returning a string which had a Field Separator character at the end, and that was the illegal character.  I was also using these strings in my test code.  I pasted my code into notepad++ and toggled on "Show Hidden Characters" and I could see the FS character then. After removing the FS, everything ran properly.  Thank you all for helping me test the code, especially @Dynguss.

Any time VS gives the Illegal Character exception, check for potential hidden characters!

Comment: Just add another spin to what can possibly go wrong. If you read a file path from configuration somewhere. Make sure you don't tail an "invisible" empty new line after the actual file path. My colleague has been bitten once when reading a CRM plugin configuration value as a file path.

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

```
string dirIni = @"C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\MyApp 4.0\INI";
string fileIni = "PWTRANSACTION.INI";
string transIniFullFileName = Path.Combine(dirIni, fileIni);
```

and to avoid hardcoding the Local Application Data folder:

```
string localAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
string dirIni = @"MyApp 4.0\INI";
string fileIni = "PWTRANSACTION.INI";
string transIniFullFileName = Path.Combine(localAppData, dirIni, fileIni);
```

By the way the following two string declarations are **perfectly identical**:

```
string transIniFullFileName = "C:\\Users\\Dan\\AppData\\Local\\MyApp 4.0\\INI\\PWTRANSACTION.INI";
string transIniFullFileName = @"C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\MyApp 4.0\INI\PWTRANSACTION.INI";
```

So if you are saying that the first fails but the second succeeds, well, I guess there's something else that's failing and you are not showing us your real code.

Comment: This looks completely reasonable (and I completely agree with using `Path.Combine` as a general rule when dealing with paths).  I have no idea why it got downvoted?

Comment: @sybkar  It got downvoted because it didn't actually address the question

Comment: @SamIam, I am addressing the question in the second part of my answer (after providing what I consider the correct approach): `So if you are saying that the first fails but the second succeeds, well, I guess there's something else that's failing and you are not showing us your real code.`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and for me it was caused by using a string instead of a path in StreamReader

```
string[] blocks = content.Split(';');
        foreach(string block in blocks)
        {
            StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader(block);
            Debug.WriteLine(block);
        }
```

I removed the StreamReader line and got what I wanted.

```
string[] blocks = content.Split(';');
        foreach(string block in blocks)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(block);               
        }
```